# Property formGroup is not provided by any applicable directives nor by form element (Specifically Angular CLI 13.0.4)

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli, angular-directive

**This is not an issue with importing `ReactiveFormsModule` or the `FormsModule`**

I already have those imported in app.module.ts and in the module where I am having this issue:

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ...
```

So this error occurs when I add the `[formGroup]` property and the `formControlName` attribute to the `.html file`

```
<form  [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="doLogin()" class="m-t" role="form" action="index.html">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="username" placeholder="Username" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
  </div>
</form>
```

This error started after **I upgraded the CLI from `12.1.0` to `13.0.4`**

If I downgrade to the previous version, the error goes away.

I have deleted the node modules folder and re-run `npm install`

Since this version of the CLI was released [7 days ago](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli), I can't find any solutions to this error. I have also gone to the [angular cli issues page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues) on Github and nothing has been raised there yet.

I'd appreciate any suggestions to fix this. Downgrading is not an option.

Comment: Give me your formGroup code inside component file

Comment: @GRD It's nothing fancy  `this.loginForm = fb.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });`

Comment: You have only one app.module or any other module you have ?

Comment: @GRD Like I said, this isn't an issue with module imports or anything. I have other modules and I have the right imports in them. This is a bug in Angular CLI

Comment: @OjonugwaJudeOchalifu did you ever find a solution to this im currently experiencing the same exact issue with angular/cli: 13.2.2?

Comment: @After_Sunset Sadly I didn't. I just copy an old project where it works and add my new project code to it. I also noticed that the issue happened on Intellij and not on Webstorm. I haven't been able to find out why that this but try changing your IDE or something.

Comment: Is there any update on this question?

Comment: @FatemeFazli nothing, till date

Comment: same problem with [fromGroup], (ngSubmit) and formControlName. is there any issue raised?

Comment: I have this problem with v13.3.11

Comment: @FatemehFazli, Hey, how are you doing? Are you ok? This is a long time I haven't heard from you. Is that everything alright?